# How to export Bootstrap Data table all rows to excel?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am new to bootstrap, i need to export table content to excel file, for that i have used `jquery.table2excel.js`. While exporting the content it omits the thead and tfoot. How can i include the tfoot and thead in the excel file. Kindly suggest me to achieve this one.

```
$(function() {
    $("#target").click(function() {
        $('<table>')
            .append(
                $("#example2").DataTable().$('tr').clone()
            )
            .table2excel({
                exclude: ".excludeThisClass",
                name: "Worksheet Name",
                filename: "SomeFile" //do not include extension
            });$("#example2").dataTable();
        });
    });
```

my Html table look like this,

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Process</th>
            <th>count</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1<td>
            <td>2015-11-04<td>
            <td>Java<td>
            <td>10<td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot class="bg-gray">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Summary</th>
            <th>10</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
<table>
```

To sort, search and paginate the table i have used the below code.

```
 $(function() {
    $('#example2').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false
    });
});
```

Comment: @madalinivascu i have added html table.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Process</th>
            <th>count</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1<td>
            <td>2015-11-04<td>
            <td>Java<td>
            <td>10<td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot class="bg-gray">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Summary</th>
            <th>10</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
<table>
    <button>save</button>
```

js:

```
$('button').click(function(){
$("#example2").table2excel({
                    exclude: ".noExl",
                    name: "Excel Document Name",
                    filename: "myFileName",
                    exclude_img: true,
                    exclude_links: true,
                    exclude_inputs: true
})
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L5qtvzq1/

Comment: Ya its working fine. But In my code i have used additional jquery command to sort, paginate the table. this can affect the table export. like the foot content print after the thead.